# lava lamp menu url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using a JavaScript plugin from the following site:
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

It uses the following: `<a href="#">My Link</a>`

HTML in order to set up any number of text buttons in a `lavalamp` menu. Included in the head of the document is the following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#3").lavaLamp({
        fx:"backout", 
        speed:600,
        click: function(event, menuItem) {
            //my callback should go here
            return false;
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The `menuItem` must identify the menu item that was clicked, but I can't seem to figure out how to attach an external html document URL to each individual `menuItem`. can anybody straighten me out, or at least give me a tutorial link that explains this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/url_here/test.html">My Link</a>
```

Specify the url in `href` attribute of the anchor. I'm guessing the callback is if you want to perform some action, or maybe load the content in via ajax and prevent the default action. But if you don't want any of that, then specifying the url in the link should take you to the page on click.